# How does my iPod touch knows my location (if it doesn't have a GPS)?

Tags: ipod-touch, geolocation

If there's no GPS in the iPod, how can it know (with such a good precision) my location?

Comment: Applies to the non-3G iPad as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

GPS uses satellites to triangulate your position with great accuracy, however there are other ways to get a fix provided you can triangulate via other means.  Apple uses a database of WIFI networks with known locations to help ascertain your location in some instances (i.e. if you can see WIFI networks A B and E, then you must be approximately located at Z for example).  Also, using cellular information you can do a similar thing by noting which cells you are able to see and the relative signal strengths you are receiving from them.

EDIT: Also, it is possible with a lesser degree of accuracy to estimate your location just by using your IP address.  This can be tracked down to a certain extent and while likely not sufficient to be accurate by itself, when you combine this with all the other methods above you can start to get a picture with more accuracy.

Comment: Thanks! I also just found a comment telling that Apple uses the technology from this enterprise: http://www.skyhookwireless.com/howitworks/

Comment: No problem - Skyhook (& Others) were used up until OS3.1,  From 3.2 onwards, Apple created and used their own database - see here for more http://techcrunch.com/2010/07/29/apple-location/